# Stored procedure doesn't return any row but same query returns proper data

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [SPmainReport]
@startDate date = null,
@endDate date = null,
@customerName varchar = null,

AS
SELECT Distinct
    VI.Code as CustomerCode, VI.Name as CustomerName, VI.Area as CustomerArea, VI.[Address] as [address], CP.ProductName as ProductName, CP.ProductQuantity as Quantity
from 
VendorTrading VT inner join CustomerProducts CP on VT.Id = CP.VendorTradingId inner join VendorInfo VI on VT.VendorId = VI.Id
where
 (VT.Tradedate between isnull(@startDate,VT.Tradedate) and isnull(@endDate,VT.Tradedate))
 and VI.Name = ISNULL(@customerName, VI.Name)
```

On execution it doesn't return any value but if I execute this query:

```
    SELECT Distinct
    VI.Code as CustomerCode, VI.Name as CustomerName, VI.Area as CustomerArea, VI.[Address] as [address], CP.ProductName as ProductName, CP.ProductQuantity as Quantity
from 
VendorTrading VT inner join CustomerProducts CP on VT.Id = CP.VendorTradingId inner join VendorInfo VI on VT.VendorId = VI.Id
where
 (VT.Tradedate between isnull(@startDate,VT.Tradedate) and isnull(@endDate,VT.Tradedate))
 and VI.Name = ISNULL('John', VI.Name)
```

It return exactly required data. I am totally confused why it is happening. There is no difference at all. I am making sure scripts are running on same database and it also contains perfect data. here is SP execution script:

```
USE [E:\SANDWICH3\ABC\BIN\DEBUG\DATABASE\ABC.MDF]
GO

DECLARE @return_value Int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SPmainReport]
    @startDate = '2015-12-25',
    @endDate = '2015-12-25',
    @customerName = N'John'

SELECT  @return_value as 'Return Value'

GO
```

One more strange I have noticed is that If I modify this SP and limit conditions with just DATES, not name. It works fine then.
I am working on Visual Studio 2013 Interface of SQL server. Not management studio (In case it does matter)

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx (always assign lengths to variable types) & http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/ (why is your database named `E:\SANDWICH3\ABC\BIN\DEBUG\DATABASE\ABC.MDF` instead of just `ABC`?)

Comment: Name is still ABC, rest is destination path. As I mentioned I am using Visual Studio Interface

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In SQL Server, *always* use a length parameter when using `varchar()` and `char()` and related types:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPmainReport (
    @startDate date = null,
    @endDate date = null,
    @customerName varchar(255) = null
)
BEGIN
    . . . 
END;
```

Most customer names probably have more than one character.

Comment: Because if you **don't** specify a length, then `@customerName varchar` ends up being **exactly --1-- character** long!

Comment: Oh man! You saved my whole night. Thanks a billion. What a silly mistake it was. Thank God I didn't wasted my further hours and asked here. I already wasted couple of hours figuring it out. Thanks a ton @Gordon Linof